# String array attribute in weka

Tags: java, string, classification, weka, arff

I need a weka training file (arff) to have a name (String) and an array of Strings associated with that name, such that the classifier associates the name with those strings when I run it on any text. For this task, how do I make an attribute in weka that is a String array? Or is there any alternative way to do this?

(I'm using Naive Bayes Classifier)

For example:
Deepika Shah, Voracious reader, funny, pretty

So if I have a sentence with any of the strings given above with Deepika Shah, it should classify the sentence as being about Deepika Shah.

EDIT:
I need to classify a sentence as being about a name, using the words and phrases in the sentence. So I'm giving a set of Strings that are associated with a name and what name they are associated with. The classifier should find the class from the sentence. Or alternatively, after I extract features from the sentence (Assume I have extracted features).

Comment: So is it that your name is class you want to predict for array of strings? Can you please provide atleast one example so that we can get clear idea.

Comment: Yes, the name is the class.

Comment: Then just use StringToWordVector filter ( I suppose that your string array is array of words like say "You are a nice guy ")' on your String array. In StringToWordvector class you can just convert String array(sentence consisting of one or more words) in N-grams where you can specify any valuse of N through Tokenizer class. You need to specify String array as String attribute n arff file. Include it's value('You are a nice guy') in quotes in arff file. If you could not understand this comment let me know I will provide in detail anser in answer section.

Comment: Yes, I didn't quite understand your answer. Also, My string array is the "voracious reader", "funny", "pretty" part of the example, Deepika Shah being the class.

Comment: Is it really a classification task? How many values do you have for class attribute? Will you please explain your problem in detail with training & testing set details.

Comment: For class attribute I have around 10,000 values. So I was thinking I would put it's attribute as String instead of nominal. (I've edited the question, I hope it's more clear now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arff file need to be in this format:

```
@Relation testRelation

@attribute firstAtr string
@attribute secondAtr string
@attribute thirdAtr string
@attribute yourClass {Deepika Shah, secondClass, ...other classes listed here}

@data
"Voracious reader","funny"," pretty",Deepika Shah

...more data here
```

Then you can import your arff file in weka.

Now you need to trasform String values to numbers. To do that you have to use the `weka->unsupervised->attribute->StringToWordVector` filter located in Filter section at preprocess tab.
You can click on the filter to tune parametres like term representation (tf,tf-idf) ,stopwords, stemmer algorithms, n-grams etc. 
Then you click apply.

After this process is finished you are ready to proceed to the classify tab and continue with the classification.You can select your classifier and you are good to go.

Note: You need to select the nominal class `(Nom)yourClass`(located under test options) to get the start button clickable.

Note2: if your sting attributes are fixed values like funny,sad,neutral etc you can use nominal attributes instead of strings

---

*p.s a nice example incorporating all the above can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSZ9jQy1sfE*

Comment: My problem is that the number of String attributes for each class can be different. Deepika Shah may have 3 Strings to describe her, Katrina Kaif may have 5 Strings, and so on. What do I do in this case?

Comment: What do you mean 3 strings? If you mean that there are n strings to describe one class then you should manually replace all n strings with one universal class. Eg if Deepika Shah, blablabla1 , blablabla2 refer to the same class then replace all blablabla1 and  blablabla2 with Deepika Shah

Comment: No, I mean like how you have firstAtr, secondAtr, thirdAtr, etc. I have n number of attributes.

Comment: You can have just one attribute and concatenate all string attributes that needed e.g "Voracious reader funny pretty",Deepika Shah

Comment: Will the different string attributes still be seen as separate? Also, what will the delimiter be between the string attributes (In the quotes)?

Comment: No delimeter is needed. Just use all word attributes as single string ,Anyway StringToWordVector will convert them to N-Grams

Comment: yes its the same thing. Weka will automatically transform your strings to vectors depending on what representation you will set on your stringToWordVector filter